# Linux[Ubuntu 16.04]-Installing MATLAB engine for Anaconda Python3

Tags: linux, matlab, python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to get Matlab's python engine to work with my Anaconda installation on Linux. But I'm not quite getting it right.

Anaconda's Python version: 3.6 (created a virtual-env for python 3.4)

Matlab Version: 2016b

Path to matlab root: /usr/local/MATLAB

Path to Anaconda: /home/fire-trail/anaconda3

Virtual env: py34

I installed matlab engine via official documentation from mathworks but it installs it in the default Linux Python installation and that too in Python 2.7

I want Anaconda 3.4 virtual env (py34) to find matlab engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it myself. Just copied the matlab folder which was formed in matlab directory for  py2.7 to my anaconda's virtual-env's site-packages.

According to the paths mentioned above in question, you need to do this on linux terminal.

`cp /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/engines/python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matlab /home/fire-trail/anaconda3/envs/py34/lib/python3.4`

and it will work with py34 in anaconda.

remember that min requirement for matlab engine in linux is, matlab 2014b and python 2.7

hope this helps other.